# Spark - TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
df2.groupBy(df2.item_type,df2.product_id)\
    .count()\
    .where(f.col('row' =<3))\
    .withColumn('row',f.row_number().over(\
    Window.partitionBy("item_type")\
    .orderBy(f.col('count')))).show()
```

But I'm having this error: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'. I would like to know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: something wrong here, `.where(f.col('row' =<3))`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in `where` clause

```
...
.where(f.col('row') <= 3)
...
```

I can not add a comment.
Replace `row` with the name of the `column name` you need to filter.

`f.col('row')` should be replaced with `f.col('column_name_you_want_to_filter')`.For example:`f.col('product_id')`.

Comment: If I execute like this I have the following error: "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`row`' given input columns: [item_type, product_id, Where is the problem now? :(

Comment: What do you mean? row is the name of the column. I don't understand.. Can you reply the code please?

Comment: The column that I want to filter is "row".I think i have to convert the column row string to int

Answer (score -1):

I think 'row' is a string <= int